# Cassandra version upgrade

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

I am currently using Cassandra 1.2.19 and cqlsh 3.1.8. I want to upgrade Cassandra version to 2.1.7. Which things do I need to keep in consideration for upgrading?

If I upgrade the version, will there occur any problem to maintain the node, add new node or remove the node?

Will secondary index work properly after upgrading?

What is the step by step procedure to upgrade it?

Comment: Take a snapshot of your data and schema on every node as a precautionary measure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to Cassandra 2.0.x first.

Please follow the advise as can be found here:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandra_g.html
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.5/NEWS.txt